# Can't seem to output stuff that matches the dictionary

Tags: c#, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to make a program, and I can't seem to get it to output everything that matches something that should already be indexed in a dictionary.

This is the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace LogParser
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        var counterLine = 0;
        var counterTimeout = 0;
        var line = string.Empty;
        var previousLine = string.Empty;
        var previousDt = DateTime.MaxValue;
        var regexTID = new Regex(@"<\w{3}: \d{10}>");
        var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{4}");
        var TID = string.Empty;




        try
        {
            var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\Jan\\Desktop\\api_fiter_sql.log"); // args[0] - ker nevemo kje bo datoteka, jo uporabnik sam doda

            Console.WriteLine("V ozadju izpisujemo vse pomembne stvari, .txt dokumenta bosta vidna na vašem namizju.\n" +
                "Profesionalno branje logov se začenja: (© Ascaldera D.O.O. - 2018)\n");

            var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "log_output.txt"), true);
            var TIDwriter = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TID_output.txt"), true);

            long position = 0;
            long previousPosition = 0;

            var TupleList = new List<Tuple<long, long, string>>();

            Dictionary<string, List<long>> TIDdict = new Dictionary<string, List<long>>(); // shranjujemo vse linije
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                counterLine++;
                Match t = regexTID.Match(line);
                if (t.Success)
                {
                    //TIDwriter.WriteLine(TID);
                    TID = t.Value;

                    if (!TIDdict.ContainsKey(TID))
                    {
                        TIDdict.Add(TID, new List<long>());
                    }
                    TIDdict[TID].Add(position);

                    foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(line))
                    {
                        var dt = new DateTime();
                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "HH:mm:ss.ffff", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                        {
                            if ((dt - previousDt).TotalSeconds > 1)
                            {
                                counterTimeout++;
                                // Console.WriteLine(previousLine); // timeout
                                // Console.WriteLine(line + "\n\n\n"); // linija za timeoutom
                                writer.WriteLine(previousLine);
                                writer.WriteLine(line + Environment.NewLine);
                                TupleList.Add(new Tuple<long, long, string>(previousPosition, position, TID));
                            }

                            previousLine = line;
                            previousDt = dt;
                            previousPosition = position;
                        }

                    }
                }

                position += line.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length;
            }

            foreach (var TIDout in TupleList)
            {
                if ((TIDout.Item1 + TIDout.Item2 + TIDout.Item3).Equals(TIDdict[TID]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(TIDout);
                }
            }

            file.Close();
            writer.Close();
            TIDwriter.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("\nBranje logov je končano. Prebrali smo: {0} vrstic ter izpisali " +
                              "{1} vrstic, kjer je bil timeout v datoteko.", counterLine, counterTimeout);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.OpenStandardError();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            Console.OpenStandardError();
            Console.WriteLine("Uporaba: {0} LOG_DATOTEKA", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the part of the code that should output every line in the .log file that matches the stuff in the dictionary. I'd assume I'm doing something greatly wrong with how I'm trying to output it, because it doesn't even output a normal string like "Success!".

```
                    foreach (var TIDout in TupleList)
                {
                    if ((TIDout.Item1 + TIDout.Item2 + TIDout.Item3).Equals(TIDdict[TID]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(TIDout);
                    }
                }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: i.e. don't just dump all your code into a question.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? I mean, stick some break points in there and **actually** look at the values in your dictionary and your tuples?

Comment: @Liam Seeing how I posted the code that I'm certain doesn't work at the bottom of the OP, I thought it would be enough? I've posted the rest of the code, as it relates to one another.

Comment: @MattJones Yes, I have, the breakpoints don't tell me anything. Which is why I'm confused. I'd assume you can't do it like I'm doing, but I'm not certain. I'm new.

Comment: Ok so what are the values of `TIDout.Item1`, etc. and what is in your dictionary? *the breakpoints don't tell me anything* really? Because you should be able to see the above

Comment: what are you trying to do here? You seem to be trying to parse a SQL file using Regex? Why? This code is very hard to read

Comment: I'm parsing a log file made by BMC Remedy. One regex outputs timeouts (anything that is datetime over 1 seconds), one regex file outputs (this also gets saved into the dictionary) <TID: 0000000000>. The TIDs differ for each action that happens. Now when a timeout happens, I want to search for that TID in the dictionary, and then output all of the TIDs related (whole lines) to that "timeout TID", and I want to do that for every timeout that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary key (`TID`) which controls the output to the console, is not guaranteed to have a value when you expect it to. And, if it does have a value, it will be the **last** regular expression match from the file.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that you are incorrectly doing your regular expression matching, and therefore, the TupleList is never going to be populated.

- Regex.Match() will return one Match object.
- Regex.Matches() returns a MatchCollection (essentially multiple Match objects) which you need to iterate over.

  ```
  ...
  Match t = regexTID.Match(line);
  if (t.Success)
  {
      //TIDwriter.WriteLine(TID);
      TID = t.Value;

      if (!TIDdict.ContainsKey(TID))
      {
          TIDdict.Add(TID, new List<long>());
      }
      TIDdict[TID].Add(position);

      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{4}");
      // Use foreach-loop.
      foreach (Match m in matches)
      {
          foreach (Capture capture in m.Captures)
          {
               var dt = new DateTime();
               if (DateTime.TryParseExact(capture.Value, "HH:mm:ss.ffff", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
               {
                   if ((dt - previousDt).TotalSeconds > 1)
                   {
                       counterTimeout++;
                       writer.WriteLine(previousLine);
                       writer.WriteLine(line + Environment.NewLine);
                       TupleList.Add(new Tuple<long, long, string>(previousPosition, position, TID));
                   }

                   previousLine = line;
                   previousDt = dt;
                   previousPosition = position;
               }   
          }
      }
  }
  ...
  ```

Comment: Even though it's in a while loop? As TID = t.Value?

Comment: The for loop is outside the while loop... if you move it inside, it might solve your problems.

Comment: @GhostyIs1337 To clarify, your `foreach` loop where you are writing out the contents of the dictionary to the console, is outside the main `while` loop. Yes, the value of `TID` potentially changes inside the while loop, but once you exit the loop, `TID` doesn't change again.

Comment: Same issue, even if it's inside the while loop. I've figured (so far) that, the dictionary fills up, but TIDout is null. https://i.imgur.com/c9UpIcB.png

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `TupleList.Add(new Tuple<long, long, string>(previousPosition, position, TID));`

The image you supplied indicates that TupleList is empty, so maybe nothing ever gets added to it?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wQRmLL1.png

I'm guessing it's not getting filled up?

Comment: @GhostyIs1337 I have updated my answer - It was becoming too long to explain in comments :)

Comment: Hey thanks! One thing though, in MatchCollections; Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' to 'string'

For 'regex'. :p

Comment: @GhostyIs1337 Sorry - I missed that. Regex.Matches() takes two string arguments. `regex` in your context was a Regex object. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Best regards.